# Why doesn't tkinter import on CentOs 7

Tags: python, tkinter, centos7

I have the python3-tkinter installed, as shown below:

```
$ sudo yum install python3-tkinter
[sudo] password for abigail: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.supremebytes.com
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
 * extras: mirror.supremebytes.com
 * ius: mirrors.kernel.org
 * nux-dextop: li.nux.ro
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.web-ster.com
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.web-ster.com
 * updates: mirror.supremebytes.com
Package python3-tkinter-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

$ /usr/bin/python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jun 27 2016, 14:02:55) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

It looks like it's because it is the version 'tkiner-3.3', but 'tkinter-3.5'. I tried use /usr/bin/python3.3, then it can import tkinter correctly.

How to install tkinter-3.5 for Python3.5?

Comment: Look at the version that is installed, and the version of python you are running. They are incompatible.

Comment: You mean the tkinter is for python 2.7? Please see my update.

Comment: In python in python 2.7 the module is named `Tkinter`

Comment: Why doesn't python3 doesn't work? I installed and tried both.

Comment: It's probably still version differences. Read the messages closely. You have python 3.5.2 but installed tkinter 3.3.2

Comment: yes, but the "yum install python3-tkinter" only installed 3.3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129398/discussion-between-user697911-and-bryan-oakley).

Answer (score 3):

You have both IUS and nux-desktop repos enabled.  It appears that nux-desktop has a package named python3 of version 3.3.2, with the related python3-tkinter package.  IUS on the other hand has packages for python34u (3.4.6), python35u (3.5.3), and python36u (3.6.0), all with corresponding tkinter packages.  So if you want to be able to `import tkinter` inside a python3.5 REPL, then run:

```
yum install python35u-tkinter
```

Answer (score 3):

For `Python 3.6.x` on `CentOS 7.4`, install:

```
$ sudo yum install python36-tkinter
```

You need to have `EPEL` repository configured.

Comment: This works to install the package, but somehow python 3.6 still can't import it.

Answer (score 1):

For tkinter installation for Python3.5:

1. `yum -y install tkinter tcl-devel tk-devel`
2. `vim ......./Python3.5.#/Modules/Setup.dist`, remove the comment symbol before the following lines:

   `_tkinter _tkinter.c tkappinit.c -
   -L/usr/local/lib \
   -I/usr/local/include \
   -ltk8.5 -ltcl8.5 \ #defualt as 8.2
   -lX11`
3. configure and install

   `./configure
   make
   make install`

Answer (score 0):

For centos 7.6, python 3.4.9, resolve my issue by:

> yum install python34-tkinter.x86_64