# How to install tkinter on python3.6 - reconfigure?

Tags: python, tkinter, centos7

I'm operating in a somewhat fresh Centos7 environment and it did not appear to ship with tkinter. Python3.6 runs fine, but import tkinter does not find any module. I downloaded ActiveTcl, but the next step according to "option 3" here: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html is to download, configure, and install python. Is there a way I can point my existing python 3.6 environment to find the version of Tcl?

Alternatively, any easier way to get tkinter so I can use matplotlib would be great.

Comment: Is pip not working?

Comment: pip3.6 is not finding any tkinter, Tkinter, Tk, or tk packages. yum install python36-T/tkinter isn't working, either.

I do have it available in python 2.7 and python 3.3, though..

Comment: [See if this can help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878944/why-doesnt-tkinter-import-on-centos-7)

Comment: Yes! That was perfect! Thank you.

Comment: It is more or less a duplicate. However, I didn't come across that page in my searches and I think this one may be worded such that it is more readily discoverable. I'll leave it to your discretion whether or not this post is flagged duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ethan Field's comment above I see that the correct syntax to install tkinter in this scenario is

```
    sudo yum install python36u-tkinter
```

That u was critical.